# How to modify SLF4J log output

Tags: java, slf4j

how can I supress the classnames in sl4j?

```
public class LogManager {
  static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classname);

  static void log(String sender, String msg) {
    logger.info(sender + " - " + msg);       
  }
}
```

The output of this its something like this:

```
2018-05-23 16:15:41,000 [ 196598]   WARN - [classname] - [sender] - [msg]
```

how can I remove the classname?

Other questions: Is there a way to remove the loglevel? What is the number "[ 196598]" in the string and how can it be removed?

Comment: This depends on the configuration of the underlying logging implementation used. Which slf4j implementation library are you using?

Comment: How can I check the underlying logging implementation? By the packagename of the lib?

Comment: by knowing what you are using in your application...

Comment: Iam using these two packages for logging: org.slf4j.Logger; org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
my ide is intellij idea.

Comment: And what logging libraries have you added to your application?

Comment: Example of logging libraries would be logback, or a combination of log4j-over-slf4j and log4j.

Comment: @BobDalgleish `log4j-over-slf4j` does the reverse: applications using that library instead of log4j will delegate logging to slf4j (which will then delegate to the underlying `slf4-<whatever>` implementation).

Comment: In the external library folder are log4j, sl4j-api and sl4k-log4j.

Comment: Christian, slf4j is just an API, it is not a logging implementation. You are using the API, but to actual log, you need to have an actual implementation. Eg logback, log4j2, slf4j-jcl + jcl, slf4j-jdk14 (java.util.logging), slf4j-simple, etc.

Comment: Then you need to check the log4j configuration. Check their documentation.

Comment: I have found the properties-file from intellij. Iam using log4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Log4j** you can use the `org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout` to format the logging information.

`conversionPattern` Sets the conversion pattern. Default is `%r [%t] %p %c %x - %m%n`.

`c` -   Used to output the category of the logging event.

For example, for the category name `"a.b.c"` the pattern `%c{2}` will output `"b.c".`

`C` - Used to output the fully qualified class name of the caller issuing the logging request.

For example, for the class name `"org.apache.xyz.SomeClass"`, the pattern `%C{1}` will output `"SomeClass"`.

Define the layout for file appender `log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%t-%x-%-5p-%-C{1}:%m%n`

This is how you need to provide in the config file of log4j.

Comment: Iam dont find the conversionPattern method in my org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout class.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Did my answer helped you. If it helped you consider accepting it.